# Can I have common zookeeper for both storm and kafka

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-storm, apache-kafka

I have configured single node kafka with the zookeeper (port:2181) and now I want to configure the Storm with two node using a single zookeeper. Can I use the same zookeeper which i used for kafka or I can use separate zookeeper for Storm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can .. same zookeeper cluster can be used for handling multiple application.
Setting up zookeeper is very straight forward in storm you can specify list of zookeeper node and port as

```
    storm.zookeeper.servers:
      - "localhost"
    storm.zookeeper.port: 2181
    storm.zookeeper.root: "/storm"
```

[here is a sample file](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/conf/defaults.yaml)